# SCSS function returning an Import

Tags: import, sass

I'm looking to create a function that returns an @import. Ideally something like this:

```
@function google_fonts($font, $weights...) {
    $result: 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=#{$font}:#{$weights}';
    @return @import url($result);
}
google_fonts('Open Sans', 400, 700);
```

Is something like this possible, or is there a work around to achieve something similar?

Comment: Have you tried it? I always just import fonts in my variables file

Comment: I have tried it with no luck. It seems you can only call a function within a CSS property. calling `google_fonts('Open Sans', 400, 700)` outside of a CSS selector is therefore invalid.

Comment: This is basically a mixin, you can only use mixins in a property. A function is something that the compiler compiles on its own into CSS. Such as grids, font szes etc

Comment: @Brad Thanks for the input. It seems that I'll need to find a workaround that doesn't include the `@import` within the function / mixin!

Thanks for the help!